# How to add a time control panel to a FuncAnimation from matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I am currently using [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) to display an animation of my work, on a figure.

It is working very well, and I understand the arguments I am using ( interval, time range , ...) However, I was wondering if there was a way to implement (maybe directly to the figure) a panel containing the animation, a scroll-bar or whatever, which allows me to :

- Move forward or backwards quickly to the time zone of interest.
- Show at what point of the animation I am ( 10%, then 20%,...).

Basically, is a way to control the animation in python on the figure like the way I would control it as a video file played by a video player?

If needed, this is what looks like the code for this animation :

```
    def init():
        im1.set_data(XYslice[0, :, :])
        im2.set_data(XZslice[0, Nplans/2:, :])
        return([im1, im2])

    def animate(t):
       im1.set_data(XYslice[t, :, :])
       im2.set_data(XZslice[t, Nplans/2:, :])
       return [im1, im2]

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(Ntime), interval=200,
                                 blit=True, init_func=init, repeat=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are talking about is a GUI. The simplest example uses the matplotlib inbuilt [widgets](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

#Setup figure and data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
delta = 0.5
t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
x = np.arange(-3.0, 4.001, delta)
y = np.arange(-4.0, 3.001, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 5.
cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
im = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axtime = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
stime = Slider(axtime, 'Time', 0.0, 100.0, valinit=50.0)

#Routines to reset and update sliding bar
def reset(event):
    stime.reset()

def update(val):
    time = stime.val/10.
    Z = (Z1 - Z2) * time
    im.set_array(Z.ravel())
    fig.canvas.draw()

#Bind sliding bar and reset button  
stime.on_changed(update)
resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

This should be a start. If you want it to look better (and add more functionality) then you need to go to a GUI framework like `wxpython`, check out [this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/MatplotlibFourierDemo) example.

An example which is more inline with your data-structure would go as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

#Setup figure and data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
delta = 0.5
t = np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 256)
x = np.linspace(-4.0, 4.001, 512)
y = np.linspace(-4.0, 4.001, 512)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
XZslice = np.zeros((256,512,512))
for i in range(t.shape[0]):
    XZslice[i,:,:] = (Z1 - Z2) * t[i]/10.
cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
im = ax.pcolormesh(XZslice[128,:,:], cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axtime = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
stime = Slider(axtime, 'Time', 0.0, 100.0, valinit=50.0)

#Routines to reset and update sliding bar
def reset(event):
    stime.reset()

def update(val):
    time = int(stime.val/100.* 256)
    im.set_array(XZslice[time,:,:].ravel())
    fig.canvas.draw()

#Bind sliding bar and reset button  
stime.on_changed(update)
resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is great ! 

I am excited to try to adapt it to my work.
Thank you very much !

Comment: What you gave me is great.
But I was too enthousiast, and now have trouble making it work with my specific situation.

I do not know how to replace the data you chose to display as an example for me by my data. 
I have a file having for shapes : 256,512,512.
256 is the time points, and both 512 are for X and Y each.
I think all my trouble comes from the meaning of Z and how to use it like in your example

Comment: GUI programming is a little strange when you first start. I've added a version which moves through results in an array of size 256,512,512. The main thing to notice is that `stime` is instantiated as a slider object,  `stime.on_changed(update)` binds the routine `update` so this routine is called every time the slider changes value and `stime.val` gives the current value on the slider. I assumed you wanted a colormesh. You could add a slider for y location which changes the index on your array if you wanted to plot line data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! 

So I tried what you kindly gave me.
I added the code at the end of my previous work. So i wanted to try your thing in a third figure ( figure  1 is my animation, figure 2 are some plots I use).
So what do I get ? I nicely get the GUI working with the animation being abled to be time shifted as required

BUT

the data from my main animation are now weird,not totally wrong but still weird, and so I can not say it is working ahah

Comment: I removed the first part of the script. So now i have my data, and what you gave me .
I have the same weird result. Is it normal that the first picture, the one at 50 (defined in the script ), does not look at all the same as the others, and when I go back to 50% I do not have the same thing as when it openned ? ^^'

Comment: hmm, I think you will have trouble using widgets in the same figure as an animation. Typically a GUI runs an endless loop checking for user input (e.g. in the form of slider changes). Doubt this will play well with animation. If you need both together, perhaps try two instances of python, one gui and one animation? I've noticed the initial difference when using `colormesh(X,Y,Z)`, I think it is because the first call specifies the X and Z locations while the `set_array` doesn't. You could `fig.clf(keep_observers=True)` in the update routine and perhaps entirely recreate the figure.

Comment: Hi ! I am affraid we arrive at the point where ,because I do not properly explain you the stuff, we begin to talk in different directions ^^' It s OK, you helped me a lot and gave me the right direction, it is my job now to learn it and make it work ;) Thank you and have a nice day.