# Python FuncAnimation frames overlay when Slider added to the figure

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have an animation of a 3D scatter plot. The animation is implemented using 
`FuncAnimation` from `matplotlib.animation`. Everything works fine until I add a slider to the figure. Then the frames in the animation persist and I see every new frame drawn on top of the older frames (see attached figure). I do not know well enough how the `FuncAnimation` works (trial and error) so, I can not figure out what suddenly goes wrong.

Below is a detailed explanation how I run my animation.

---

The animation is handled inside the class I have named `MyAnim`, when the class is initialized I, first, create the 3D figures using:

```
class MyAnim(object):
    """Animates points on 3D wireplot"""

    def __init__(self, [...]):

        [...]

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))            
        self.subplot = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        self.subplot._axis3don = False
```

Then I run `anim` method of `MyAnim` that starts the animation loop:

```
def anim(self):
    """Sets the animation loop"""

    frames = [...]
    self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate3d, frames, init_func = self.init, interval = 50, blit = False, repeat= False)
```

where in `self.init` I initialize a dummy scatter plot (with single transparent (`alpha = 0`) point at zero).

```
def init(self):    
   """Animation initialization"""

   self.subplot_3d_wires = self.subplot.scatter([0], [0], [0], c = RED, s = 100, alpha = 0)
   return [self.subplot_3d_wires]
```

The animation itself involves reevaluating the position of the grid points of the wire plot `next_pos` as well as the new position of the scatter points of red color (`x_red, y_red, z_red`) and of blue color (`x_blue, y_blue, z_blue`) which are then drawn on top of the wire plot.

So those two components of the plot read:

```
def animate3d(self, i):

    plt.cla() 

    [...]

    next_pos = get_next_pos(i)

    [...]

    for j in range(X_SIZE ** 2):            

        step_l = (j) * Z_SIZE
        step_r = (j + 1) * Z_SIZE
        self.subplot_3d_wires = self.subplot.plot_wireframe(next_pos[step_l:step_r, 0], 
                                                            next_pos[step_l:step_r, 1], 
                                                            next_pos[step_l:step_r, 2], 
                                                            rstride = 1, 
                                                            cstride = 1, 
                                                            alpha = 0.2, 
                                                            antialiased = True)

    [...]
    (x_red, y_red, z_red) = get_new_red(i)
    (x_blue, y_blue, z_blue) = get_new_blue(i)

    self.subplot_3d_wires = self.subplot.scatter(x_red, y_red, z_red, s = 150, c = RED,  depthshade = False, lw = 0, alpha = 1)
    self.subplot_3d_wires = self.subplot.scatter(x_blue, y_blue, z_blue, s = 150, c = BLUE,  depthshade = False, lw = 0, alpha = 1)

    [...]

    return [self.subplot_3d_wires]
```

I want to gradually replace animation with a slider bar [something along this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407665/how-to-add-a-time-control-panel-to-a-funcanimation-from-matplotlib), so  for a start I just want to add a slider (`from matplotlib.widgets import Slider`) next to my animation (not connected to the animation in any way). But just declaring silder on the figure, the animation becomes corrupted - I see my plots overlayed one on top of the other, see the figure.

I tried to instantiate the slider using

```
 axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
 axtime = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
 self.stime = Slider(axtime, 'Time', 0.0, 100.0, valinit = 50.0)
```

either in `__init__` of the class `MyAnim` or when I start the `init` method for the animation, but they produce the same result.

***What am I doing wrong here?*** Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Before the slider is added animation goes smoothly]

[image: with the slider the frames overlay one on top of the other]

Comment: Even without the Slider, the new plots should be simply added to the figure. If this is not the case then something in your code is different from what you show here. I tinkered [this minimal running example](http://pastebin.com/14NjHV0w) from your code (or from what I think you're doing) and it also adds all the points to the canvas, as would be expected. Can you find out what is different in your real case?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks, interesting... I literally just comment out the Slider and it makes the difference. I also use `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` I can not see any difference... I will try to run your code and see what I get. Anyway do you see a way to solve the overlay problem in **your** code?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you are correct, thanks! I overlooked `plt.cla()` at the start of `aniamte3d` to erase the figure.  The edited code is [here](http://pastebin.com/8hPeetvj), (I will update my post). Now the problem appears as I have described it in the post - Slider changes the appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `plt.cla()`. 
This command will clear the last active `axes` it finds on the plot. Once you add a slider, the slider's axes will be the axes to be cleared and the plot's axes stay unchanged.

The solution is therefore not let pyplot decide which axes to clear, but to explicitely state

```
self.subplot.cla()
```